# How can I put players in a team on their first join in Vanilla Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I've figured out parts of this.

I know I can use commandblocks to achieve it.

I know I can use them to add a player to a team either when they step on a pressure plate, or just have the commandblock repeat the command (though this floods chat.)

From what I gather, in the past this involved using the scoreboard. Past solutions no longer work as the syntax has changed.

I need a joining player to be forced into a team. Any method possible in vanilla Minecraft is acceptable.

I'd like to avoid using touchplate or switches as those can be broken, even unintentionally.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to prevent chat spam from command blocks you can do

```
/gamerule commandBlockOutput false
```

then you need to create a team to join

```
/team add teamName
```

and then just on repeat run

```
/team join teamName @a[team=]
```

this just joins anyone who's not in a team already to some default team.

Comment: Thanks jklw10. I think that will work.

It's not an elegant solution, But it's better than nothing.

Comment: Scratch that, This worked perfectly, even without the gamerule. Thank you.